# 32 bit hex string to floating point number in java

Tags: java, floating-point

I have the following string "`0x4B196DAF`". I want to get output like "`10055087.000000`".

My piece of code is showing a strange output like "`1.0055087E7`"

```
long l = Long.parseLong(hexval, 16);
return Float.intBitsToFloat(l.intValue());
```

I have also tried with

```
long l = Long.parseLong(hexval, 16);
return Double.longBitsToDouble(l.longValue());
```

But nothing helpful. I have check few website which showing the correct output. I can't find out the problem exactly.

Comment: maybe look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: 1.0055087E7 is simply 10055087.000000 in another notation. You want to look into java's formatting options for printing numbers. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to print it out as a string, call somewhere toString(). It will give a scientific notation after limit is met.

You can try to use:

```
int hex = 0x4B196DAF;
float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(hex);
System.out.println(f);
System.out.printf("%f", f);
```

Output ....

```
1.0055087E7
10055087.00000010055087
```

or if you want you can try using NumberFormat, which will allow you to set a minimum fraction digits:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(6);

System.out.println(nf.format(f));
```

output ....

```
10055087.000000
```

I hope it will help.